# Cassandra open port native_transport_port after a random time

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm running a cluster of 10 Cassandra 3.10 and I saw a very strange behavior: after restart, a node won't open immediately native_transport_port (9042).

After one node restart, the flow is :

- node finishes to read all commitlog,
- update all its data,
- it's visible for other nodes in the cluster,
- wait for random time (from 1 minute to hours) to open 9042 port

My logs are in DEBUG mode, and nothing is written about opening this port. 
What is happening and how can I debug this problem?

Output for several `nodetool` commands are:

- `nodetool enablebinary` does not return at all
- `nodetool compactionstats` 0 pending tasks
- `nodetool netstats` Mode: STARTING. Not sending any streams.
- `nodetool info`: Gossip active          : true
  Thrift active          : false
  Native Transport active: false

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saving your key/row cache? It tends to take a lot of time when that is the case. Also, what is your file max limit?

Comment: Yes, indeed I am saving key cache, but this was loaded quickly. The problem was with counter cache, with took 5315293 ms for 893107 keys.  For anyone who is having this problem, I saw these numbers in cassandra log. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Not a problem @banuj